# How can i read the data of headers of a post request sent by python requests?

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-requests, http-post

Looking for the help, I am making a post request to an django application with AUTH-TOKEN in the header and trying to access it on view but not able to.

```
python app
    import requests
    import json
    URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/api/" 
    request_data ={
                    'order':{
                    'id':'order.id',
                    'payment_collection_status': 'transaction_status',
                    'payment_collection_message': 'transaction_message'
                    }
                }
    
    request_headers = {'AUTH-TOKEN':'webhook_auth_token'}
    json_data = json.dumps(request_data)
    response = requests.post(url = URL,headers=request_headers, data = json_data)
    print(response)

django application view
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt 
@csrf_exempt
def request_handle(request):
    if (request.method=='POST'):
        print(request.body)
        print(request.META["AUTH-TOKEN"])
        return HttpResponse('<h1>hello</h1>')
```

but not able read the header data it is throwing an error: KeyError: 'AUTH-TOKEN'

Comment: Try this method : request.headers["AUTH-TOKEN"]

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

1. `request.META.get('HTTP_AUTH_TOKEN')`
2. `request.headers.get('AUTH-TOKEN')` if you're on Django>=2.2

More details on [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.headers)

Comment: the best small answer.